# Is there an R equivalent to Stata's ttest command

Tags: r, stata

As described in the Stata book `ttest` performs t tests on the equality of means.

```
ttest x, by(group)
```

This is a very simple command, though I can't seem to find an R equivalent. The ideal output would result in mean, std deviation and a tstat or pvalue. Preferably the command would allow a comparison of more than one mean and would allow for output in 1 table.

Comment: Look at `?t.test`. It's a very simple command in R too :)

Comment: Is there a function that creates a table that would allow for multiple variables. I tried using lapply but the output looked very messy. lapply(df[,c("x", "y", "beta")], function(x) t.test(x ~ df$firmtype, var.equal = TRUE))

Comment: You might want to look into the *broom* package - https://broom.tidymodels.org/articles/broom.html - for tidying output into a summary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `broom` provides an option to `tidy` some results.
Here is an example to show you how you can perform multiple t-tests by group. Note that this does not automatically correct for multiple testing, so bear that in mind.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(tidy(t.test(Sepal.Width)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 9
#>   Species    estimate statistic  p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method    
#>   <fct>         <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>     
#> 1 setosa         3.43      63.9 7.17e-49        49     3.32      3.54 One Sampl~
#> 2 versicolor     2.77      62.4 2.31e-48        49     2.68      2.86 One Sampl~
#> 3 virginica      2.97      65.2 2.78e-49        49     2.88      3.07 One Sampl~
#> # ... with 1 more variable: alternative <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The outputs are readily explained in the manual, accessed by `?tidy.htest`

```
alternative 
Alternative hypothesis (character).

conf.high   
Upper bound on the confidence interval for the estimate.

conf.low    
Lower bound on the confidence interval for the estimate.

estimate    
The estimated value of the regression term.

estimate1   
Sometimes two estimates are computed, such as in a two-sample t-test.

estimate2   
Sometimes two estimates are computed, such as in a two-sample t-test.

method  
Method used.

p.value 
The two-sided p-value associated with the observed statistic.

parameter   
The parameter being modeled.

statistic   
The value of a T-statistic to use in a hypothesis that the regression term is non-zero.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>